# Python - How to generate every possible way a list of 12 items can be split into 3 lists of any size (including empty)

Tags: python, arrays, list, combinations

I have 2 lists, one with 12 elements and one with 3 sub-lists.

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
b = [[],[],[]]
```

I need to write Python code which will generate every possible way in which the 12 elements in a can be distributed across the sub-lists in b. There are 3^12 (just over half a million) combinations. For example, some possible combinations would be the following:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],[],[]]
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12]]
[[1,4,12],[2,3,9,11],[5,6,7,8,10]]
```

Order does not matter within the lists. I've tried using some itertools functions such as permutation and combination but they don't seem to do what I'm looking for. I tried

```
    buildings = list(range(1,13)) #assign each building a unique id
    building_arrangement = [list(range(1,13)),[],[]] # quarries, factories, markets
    all_arrangements.append(building_arrangement)
    
    combos = itertools.combinations(buildings, 3)
    
    for combo in combos:
        print(combo)
```

But the above seems to get the combination of each of the 12 numbers individually as opposed to treating the full 12 numbers as a set and finding each unique set that can be made. I'm not sure if this can be done via any pre-existing libraries, itertools doesn't seem to provide a way to do this from what I can see in the documentation, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that each combination can be encoded by an m-ary number, where m is the number of sublists.
Iterating over all n-digit m-ary numbers (where n is the number of elements) will do the trick:

```py
N = 12
M = 3

for n in range(N**M):
    combination = [[] for __ in range(M)]
    for i in range(N):
        combination[n // 3**i % 3].append(i)
    print(combination)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've run some tests and this seems to do exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator function:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
def groups(d, n, c = []):
   if not d and len(c) == n:
      yield c
   elif d:
      for i, j in enumerate(d):
         if not c or len(c) + 1 <= n:
            yield from groups(d[:i]+d[i+1:], n, c+[[j]])
         if c:
            yield from groups(d[:i]+d[i+1:], n, c[:-1]+[[*c[-1], j]])

def results(d, n):
    s = []
    for i in groups(d, n):
       if (k:=[*map(sorted, i)]) not in s:
          yield k
          s.append(k)

r = results(a, 3)
for _ in range(10): #first 10 results
   print(next(r))
```

Output:

```
[[1], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11], [12]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, not quite what I'm looking for I'm afraid. In my case, all of the above are the same. i.e. the contents are the same regardless of the order. I need to have it so that the contents of each output are unique.

Comment: @JamesO'Neill A pretty straightforward approach, and one that enables you produce combinations from any custom input list, is to filter after producing the raw results. Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 0):

Also why not try [itertool recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), `powerset()`

```
pip install more-itertools
```

Then,

```
from more_itertools import recipes

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
tuples = recipes.powerset(a)
for tuple in tuples:
  print(tuple)
```

This will create all possible sets from the iterable given to it. You can divide it in to lists of 3 using a different funtion.